# Hex formatting within powershell object

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get hex output.  This code:

```
    get-wmiobject -class "Win32_LoggedOnUser" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -Property * | `
      Select @{Name="Antecedent";Expression={$_.Antecedent.Split('=').replace("`"","")[2]}}, `
      @{Name="Dependent";Expression={$_.Dependent.Split("`"")[1]}}
```

Will generate two columns, login name and logonID as follows:

```
Antecedent      Dependent
----------      ----------
SYSTEM          999      
LOCAL SERVICE   997      
NETWORK SERVICE 996      
<user>          347528   
<user>          6842494  
<user>          46198354 
<user>          46171169 
DWM-2           223575   
DWM-2           223551
```

Event Viewer uses the hex representation of the logonID, for example 'SYSTEM 'would be represented by 0x3e7 vs 999, or in PowerShell

```
 ps> '{0:x}' -f 999
```

I'm trying to match up with that.

I'm trying to do something along these lines:

```
    get-wmiobject -class "Win32_LoggedOnUser" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -Property * | `
      Select @{Name="Antecedent";Expression={$_.Antecedent.Split('=').replace("`"","")[2]}}, `
      @{Name="Dependent";Expression={'{0:x}' -f $_.Dependent.Split("`"")[1]}}
```

But no luck so far.

Comment: What are you trying to do in your last `Get-WmiObject` call?

Comment: Think you just need to cast to an int first. Try this: `'{0:x}' -f [int64]$_.Dependent.Split('"')[1]}`

Comment: @BenH to have the prefix 0x it has to be inserted in the format string `'0x{0:x}' -f [int64]$_.Dependent.Split("`"")[1]}`

Comment: @LotPings that got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Split()` is a string method. So the output of `$_.Dependent.Split()` will be a `[string]` and you are wanting to convert from a `int` to a `hex`. So you will want to cast to an `int` before converting. A quick look at `Dependent` also looks like the numbers are too large for an `[int32]` so `[int64]` would be best. Also as @LotPings pointed out you will want to add the `0x` prefix in your formatting string.

```
 Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_LoggedOnUser" -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Property Antecedent,Dependent |
      Select @{
           Name = 'Antecedent'
           Expression = {$_.Antecedent.Split('=').replace('"','')[2]}
      }, @{
           Name = 'Dependent'
           Expression = {'0x{0:x}' -f [int64]$_.Dependent.Split('"')[1]}
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Final code with update from @LotPings & @BenH

```
get-wmiobject -class "Win32_LoggedOnUser" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -Property * | `
  Select @{Name="Antecedent";Expression={$_.Antecedent.Split('=').replace("`"","")[2]}}, `
  @{Name="Dependent";Expression={'0x{0:x}' -f [int64]$_.Dependent.Split("`"")[1]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do what I think you're wanting to do:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogonSession | ForEach-Object {
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    "Account" = $_.GetRelated("Win32_Account").Name
    "LogonId" = "{0:X}" -f ([Int] $_.LogonId)
  }
}
```

It appears that the `LogonId` property is a string so you have to cast as `Int`. You can add the `0x` prefix if needed.

Comment: That worked, except the DWM-2 accounts didn't populate

Comment: What are "dwm-2 accounts"?

Comment: DWM stands for Desktop Window Manager. They are new accounts Win8+

Comment: Both cases are using WMI and the same classes. Perhaps change the `Name` property to something else, such as `Caption`.